# Replace text containing regular expression in terminal

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed, terminal

I would like to replace in IP address with a sed command in terminal

```
sed -i "2 s=http://*:8000=http://example.com=g" file.txt;
```

Where the * can change. I thought I could use * to replace any characters between the http:// and :8000, but it behaves like plain text.

How could I check for strings containing the http:// and :8000 part with anything between, and replace it with the http://example.com?

Comment: you need `.*` instead of `*`. This is a regex not a wildcard.

Comment: I see you're using the `g` modifier so it will do multiple replacements on the line. Be aware that `.*` is greedy, so it will match everything from the first `http://` to the last `:8000`. Then it will replace all the stuff in between those two URLs with the one replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is a quantifier that matches 0 or more occurrences of the pattern being quantified.

You want to match any amount of characters other than `/` and whitespace, that is, `[^/[:space:]]*`.

Use

```
sed -i "2 s=http://[^/[:space:]]*:8000=http://example.com=g" file.txt;
                   <------------>
```